# TypeScript: "catch" and explicitly handle unresolved generic in conditional?

Tags: typescript

I've been trying for a while now to find a real-life, but not too complex example for this. I hope this works.

We are working with `immer`, which exports a `Draft` type that looks like this (I simplified it a bit):

```
type Draft<T> = T extends object ?
    {
      -readonly [K in keyof T]:  Draft<T[K]>
    }
  : T
```

So, that type only removes the `readonly` attribute, deeply nested, from all object properties it encounters.

That works very well, until `T` is a yet-unresolved generic. In that case, it stays `Draft<T>` and cannot be assigned values of `T` (which should, given the type, always be possible).

So my question is: can I somehow detect that a type is unresolved and return something differently?

Essentially, something like

```
type Draft<T> = 
    T is unresolved ? 
      T 
    : T extends object ?
    {
      -readonly [K in keyof T]:  Draft<T[K]>
    }
  : T
```

I have prepared an example that provokes this behaviour [as a TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIgTgQwGbADwBUB8UC8V1QQAewEAdgCYDOUA9gEYBWEAxsFAPwCwAUFP1ADevAQIC0cCAgq0yAGxBQA2gGkoASzJQA1hBC0k+ALoAufvGRp0qo5hECAvvbPpevUJFgJgCDNjyCUABuCHIArhAuUA4A3G48SGFkbOqyUADm5BBw6iwAYmR+ABSa6sDqoQAKCIgAtmYw3r5YAJRCUPaJyeVppFTARWA1CPWwiCiojT5+mG2B9vwA9ItQAHTr9k58HTyLAFR7IntQAIJw6WG15OwGUB7QAORTzZgPGjRktOwIVFTq6WQEPQ5NBgLQoEM6hBSHA6IZ7lAHoEQuFImNLH4YtEHqsjvx0OAIDRbmA4LRIHBQIiURE3jVoJoWLRakNysCILi+McBATPA90G91B8vlAfn8AUCQXdwQinuMrK9OVA9ot7H0BqVylVhrUWnFtpJgGE4Fp1fqtu5CVAAGqhCK4dpIWi0Mz9HJkdLRfW8EHsJBaPCZMjZXIFVC21GYIrIu1owJOl1QABE9AQAC8k9FonreP7o8FY2Z486zCmapmHNmgA).

Outside of the function, `T` is resolved and everything works fine, but inside of the function I cannot call the child function as it expects `Draft<T>` and assumes that `T` a an argument is not compatible.

And yes, this is a bit constructed. If you want a real-life example, you can take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/305) where in addition, a conditional type over an unresolved generic takes all possible forms - and thus returns incompatible function signatures. So we've got more than one situation where I would love to find a good answer to avoid this TS behaviour :(

Comment: I doubt you can do this; normally the compiler *defers* evaluating such types; I don't think there's any behavior where you can have the compiler pre-emptively evaluate such types and have it be a *different* outcome from the type you get when `T` is known.  Even if you can find a way to do this I imagine it'd be very fragile, as it would depend on tricking the compiler.  I'd suggest using a different approach.  The example code should work with `type Draft<T> = { -readonly [K in keyof T]: Draft<T[K]> }` because primitives are skipped in mapped types.  Do you have a better [mcve]?

Comment: The "primitives are skipped in mapped types" information is new to me, that might help. The [original upstream type definition](https://github.com/immerjs/immer/blob/v4.0.0/src/immer.d.ts#L9-L26) of Draft is a little more complicated, but in the context of our library, we could opt for your simple suggestion.
This would solve our first problem, we *do* have a second problem with function signatures though that I had hoped to solve this way. I'll try and see if I can also solve it or otherwise try to provide a repro for that :)
Thank you so far!

Comment: @jcalz
Okay, after some experimentation, this does work for TS 3.6 and 3.7, but all earlier versions end up with "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite". So that's not the way to go :(

Is there anything specific I can do to optimize the reproducible I had above in the TypeScript playground? In reality it's a *lot* more complicated and has some additional consequential errors, so it was already pretty hard to extract this example out.

Comment: (PS: forgot to say: these are library types and we have to support TS down to 3.3, so some things are just not possible :( )

Comment: The usual advice is not to try to assign to unresolved conditional types.  Instead use assertions or [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAIgTgQwGbADwBUB8UC8V1QQAewEAdgCYDOUA9gEYBWEAxsFAPxQDeUAtHAgIKtMgBsQUANoBpKAEsyUANYQQtJPgC6ALliIUGWVuwBfKHvQBYAFC3QkWAmAIM2PLwBuCMQFcIllCmANy2tki+ZGzyolAA5uQQcPIsAGJkbgAUivLA8j4ACgiIALZ6MM6uWACUeplgxQhl+shoFS5umNW42J608hShNhFRebEJZEkp6dlkufliRaXllaiRymS0AO5kXTy2UFAO0AR465s7Q4cj0bGkVMD1jc3wrajtVZh73AdBv-ePHJ5QrPapXKCCYC+OBKAFDUxhGzHKAANR8-lwPCgSFotD0D2SZDiQSGtjEEHYSCUeAmUzSGTRfggmEyXnRASxOLxUAARPQEAAvHlBIJg8JkVlQbxMvS8Ll6PnFYXmUzVIA).

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find a solution for you using the type definition. I tried using the [infer keyword](https://dev.to/aexol/typescript-tutorial-infer-keyword-2cn) to see if I reach somewhere, but nothing.
But, I could find a "workaround" in the way you are using the `Draft` type in your example. I just declare a new `Draft` variable initialized by the `initialParam` with typecasting to the `Draft` type.

```js
function genericFn<T>(initialParam: Data<T>) { 
  function test(param: Draft<Data<T>>) { 
    // ...
  }

  const draft: Draft<Data<T>> = initialParam as Draft<Data<T>>;
  test(draft);
  return test;
}
```

Hope it works for you. It is not the most elegant solution, but it stop the Typescript error.

Comment: Thank you for your time. 

I'm aware of this workaround, but this is a library type, so I would have to advise all our users to use this workaround, which is why I'm trying to find a solution where this might not be required. 
So I'll leave this question open for the time being, maybe one of the TS wizards around here knows something that we have missed :)

Comment: Oh... I see. Indeed it is an interesting problem... Maybe there is a way, I will keep the eyes on this thread to see if someone can make it. If there is a way, I am really willing to know.